# How to switch between two different colors with one button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click, toggle, addeventlistener

Im trying to change between two colors when I click on the event listener using JavaScript. When I trigger the `click` event, it changes the color to black. When I click on it again, I want it to change back to the default, which is white. I think that an if statement is involved, but Im not sure how the logic would work in this case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Light Switch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" />

</head>

<body id="body">

<button id="submit">Submit
  <label id="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</button>

<script src="light.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function start() {
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  submit.addEventListener("click", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("body");
  color.style.backgroundColor = "black";
};


start();
```

Comment: I think you did not seacrh on google . check this and do changes according to you https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `toggle` function on the `classList` of that element. Add a class and toggle it.

```js
function start() {
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  submit.addEventListener("click", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("body");
  color.classList.toggle('black');
};


start();
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
   <button id="submit">Submit
      <label id="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
   </button>
</body>
```

You can also just check the current color and switch every time.

```js
function start() {
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  submit.addEventListener("click", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("body");
  var backColor = color.style.backgroundColor;
  color.style.backgroundColor = backColor === "black" ? "white" : "black";
};


start();
```

```html
<body id="body">
   <button id="submit">Submit
      <label id="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
   </button>
</body>
```

Comment: I have worked from yours separately. What about the class name, it is just an obvoius name. I don't rob anyones answer. If I should do like how you think, at least I could change the class name. Think twice before you want to write something

Comment: Though twice mate

Comment: The bad is in that. Thinking twice does not bring you to the truth

Comment: If you have even mentioned `classList` in your answer I would not have posted it. and you still not accepting the truth

Comment: One line in the two answers may match and from that you consider that I write your answer. I know the truth and for me it is not important what you think. I have tried to prove you, the rest is your problem

Comment: This did not work for me. I dont really understand why it would, as it does not specify the second color I want to change to. The second option does not work either. But thanks for the answer eitherway

Comment: The second color is that one, which was used as default. Examples work. Maybe something wrong in your code?

Comment: Nah man I copied it directly. Nothing happens, it stays white

Comment: Have you added the class in styles ?

Comment: Why use ".black" when its not a class in html?

Comment: I am about that. `toggle` needs a class

Comment: It works when running it on this site, but when I copied exact code from CSS, html, and java script and commented out all my other code, it doesnt work.... since when does logic no longer apply??

Comment: Nevermind, The problem was when I copied the HTML from this page and commented out my others stuff, it didnt include the linking of my JS or my CSS so those files were not being applied. It works now, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manipulating `backgroundColor`, You can create CSS class and add/remove it to the element using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property

```js
function start() {
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  submit.addEventListener("click", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("body");
  color.classList.toggle("black");
};


start();
```

```css
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">

  <button id="submit">Submit
  <label id="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</button>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this, i think it work for you...

```
var background = document.getElementById(id).style.background;
var btn = addEventListener("click", function (){
    if(background = "rgb(255,145,0)"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "red";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = "white";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function start() {
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click", toggle);
  };

  function toggle() {
    var color = document.getElementById("body");

    if(color.style.backgroundColor==='black')
      color.style.backgroundColor='';
    else
    color.style.backgroundColor = "black";

  };

  start();
```